# Do we need Etag and Last-Modified header when using CommonsChunkPlugin in webpack

Tags: caching, nginx, webpack, header

I am using webpack to bundle all my assets files so I get something like this.

```
bundle.7fb44c37b0db67437e35.js
vendor.495e9142a1f8334dcc8c.js
styles.bc5b7548c97362b683f5582818914909.css
```

I use chunkhash in the name so when browser caches something it doesnt cache again until hash has changed. For example if I change something in styles, bundle the files and deploy, only the hash from styles will change, others wont so browser will request from the server again just the styles file and the rest will use from memory cache.

In response header I also have **Etag** and **Last-Modified** and they change every time I deploy app for every file. Should I remove them from response? Can that confuse the browser to contact the server and see if files have changed even though hash is still the same?

Answer (score 2):

Great question. This depends largely on how the back-end is implemented and how it calculates the header values. Are the files served from our server, or something else like s3? Are we using a CDN? Are we using a framework for our application server? Who calculates these headers, the web server or the application server?

For the purposes of this answer and to keep things simple let's assume we are using the popular server framework [Express](https://expressjs.com/) with no CDN or 3rd party hosting. Like most application servers, Express **calculates `ETag` and `Last-Modified` based on the content of the file being served - not the name of the file**.

The first time a browser requests one of our files, it will receive the the `ETag` and `Last-Modified` for the resource. The next time the same resource is requested the browser will send the cached `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers to the server. The server then decides based on these headers whether the browser needs to download a new version of the resource or if the cached version is current. If the cached resource is current, the server responds with a `304 - Not Modified` status code. The status code is the key to this whole caching system - it is how the browser decides if it should use the cached resource.

To generate the `ETag` header, Express passes a binary `Buffer` representation of the response body to the `etag` module which calculates a SHA-1 hash based on the contents of the Buffer ([source: generating ETag header](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/ae0b630ac7e8f34e4ea37285f30db4b52adf8436/lib/response.js#L190) and [source: generating hash](https://github.com/jshttp/etag/blob/master/index.js#L48)). To generate the `Last-Modified` header, Express uses the file system's last modified time ([see `lastModified` in docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)).

When webpack builds a new bundle the file's binary will change even if the chunkhash is the same. This causes Express to output a different `Etag` and `Last-Modified`, **which means it will not respond with a `304` the next time the resource is requested**. Without the `304` status code, the browser will unnecessarily re-download the bundle.

#### Answer

I think the best thing to do here is disable `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers for these assets and instead use the `Expires` or `Cache-Control: max-age` header set to a date far in the future (usually 1 year). This way the browser will only re-download a bundle if it is expired or if it simply does not exist in the cache.

Comment: Hi ross, great answer, it has a lots of sense. It's been some time since I asked the question but I left ETag and Last Modified in response. The reason is that browser was still using the cached version when hash didn't change, even though Etag and Last-Modified has. 
According to your answer it should not do that. You think that different browsers have different behaviour:
Btw, my setup is just as you said, Express , no CDN or 3rd party hosting, Chrome browser.

Comment: @Igor-Vuk Interesting. I would need to see all of the request/response headers to know for sure. My guess is that you have some other header set, most likely `Cache-Control` that is overriding the Etag validation header. If you add an example i'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: It would be pretty complicated to dig up the project now but my setup was something like this.

app.use(expressStaticGzip(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'dist'), {maxAge: '1y'}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
  return next()
});
Setting maxAge for all the static files and noCache for server so that browser always contacts a server and checks if something is changed but doesnt download static files unless hash has changed. So yeah, now I remember. Browser did actually contact server because i set it like that :)

Comment: Isn't the point that the chunkhash should change when the file's binary changes (similar to Etag)? In that case, Etag can be used when the expiration is expired, and long expiration is not needed (although it can. Unless I'm missing something; in that case please do clarify.

Comment: @Trace My answer may be out of date because I tested this with an older version of webpack back in 2017. At the time I tested, webpack would produce different binary even if the source code (and chunkhash) didn't change. (Maybe webpack was including build specific info in the bundle?) This means that the ETag header could change even when chunkhash remained the same, making ETag unreliable for caching bundles. I just tested with a more recent version of webpack and it seems that the binary of the bundles no longer changes between identical builds, so yes you could use Etag as you described.

Comment: @Trace however I still think a long expiration is good idea to avoid a round trip to the server to check ETag after cache expires.